# VBA insert blank row based on max column value

Tags: excel, vba

How do I insert a blank row below the max value designated within column A? This is the best I could cobble together with searching other's posts.

```
Dim i As Range
Dim cell As Range
   Set i = Range("A:A")
   For Each cell In i.Cells
If cell.Value = Max(i) Then
   cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim MaxRow As Double
     MaxRow = Application.Match(Application.Max(Range("a:a")), Range("a:a"), 0)
        Cells(MaxRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the maximum value using worksheet functions then shift the location down one row and insert.

```
Sub xcv()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Rows(Application.Match(Application.Max(.Columns(1)), .Columns(1), 0) + 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End With
End Sub
```